# Calling methods of embedded objects

Tags: php, oop, object

Assuming we have an object that gets 3 objects in constructor:

```
$SomeObject = new Object($UrlChecker, $UrlModifier, $UrlComposer);
```

Wouldn't it be better to create an wrapper object $Url like this:

```
class Url {

 public $Modifier;
 public $Composer;
 public $Checker;

     public function __construct(){
         $this->Modifier = new UrlModifier();
         $this->Composer = new UrlComposer();
         $this->Checker = new UrlChecker();
     }
}
```

And then pass only this $Url object:

```
$Url = new Url();
$SomeObject = new Object($Url);
```

Now all the objects will be created in the $Url object and I can call their memebers within the object $SomeObject like this:

```
$Url->modifier->set_parameter($param);
```

Is it a good practice to set embedded object as public or should I create for every object a getter-method? Or maybe I should stick with the first variant by passing all three objects to the $SomeClass?

I thought I could use public methods like Java's "System.out" does, where "out" is an public member/object within the System-object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how this:

`$this->url->modifier->set_parameter($param);`

is better than this:

`$this->modifier->set_parameter($param);`

You're requiring additional steps for the caller and the callee without clear benefit. The first approach makes it appear that the methods are somehow working of the same base data (somehow stored in `$url`). However, that is not the case (your goal appears to be organization but really you should be driven by which object controls the state/base data). The base data would/should be stored in the controlling object (represented by `$this`). So, having said that...

> Is it a good practice to set embedded object as public or should I
>   create for every object a getter-method?

... you should hide the objects and create getters/setters on the main object since it needs to control (the basis of encapsulation) the injected objects (which is why you injected them in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use private variable if you intend to use $modifier, $composer, and $checker internally and create getter and setter method for those variables. It's OOP concept called encapsulation. The main purpose is to protect an object integrity by preventing users from setting the internal data of the component into an invalid or inconsistent state.